# Speed up database insertion

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I parse data from XML an insert it into my database. But these are up to 1000 Querys which must completed before the app starts. 
Because I have to use FTS3 search, the insert get significantly slowed down.

Before I added FTS3 search I used `BLOB`. This was pretty fast. How can I speed it up?

I use this FTS3 table:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + TABLE_FTS + " USING fts3(" + COL_ID + ", " + COL_KEY_ID + ", " + COL_KEY_NAME + ", "
            + COL_KEY_WEBURL + ", " + COL_KEY_MAINURL + ", " + COL_KEY_LOGO + " " + ");");
```

and I insert the String with this method:

```
      int init = 0;
      for(int t = init; t < arr.length; t++){
          Log.i(TAG, "arr["+t+"] = " + arr[t].trim());

        if(r == 1) {
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO table (id) VALUES ('" + arr[t].trim() + "')");
            id_save = arr[t].trim();
            r++;
        }else if(r == 2) {
            database.execSQL("UPDATE table SET name='" + arr[t].trim() + "' WHERE id='" + id_save + "'");
            name_save = arr[t].trim();
            r++;
        }else if(r == 3) {
            database.execSQL("UPDATE table SET weburl='" + arr[t].trim() + "' WHERE id='" + id_save + "' AND name='" + name_save + "'");
            r++;
        }else if(r == 4) {
            database.execSQL("UPDATE tables SET mainurl='" + arr[t].trim() + "' WHERE id='" + id_save + "' AND name='" + name_save + "'");
            r++;
        }else if(r == 5) {
            database.execSQL("UPDATE table SET logo='" + arr[t].trim() + "' WHERE id='" + id_save + "' AND name='" + name_save + "'");
            r = 1;
        }
```

Is there any good way to optimize it? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the speed of bulk insert.

Use **[DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper.html)** instead of **SQLiteDatabase.insert**

Comment: Thanks, how I do `UPDATE` with the InsertHelper?

Comment: Damned! Thats fast. I reduced it to only 3 seconds. Before it were about 20 seconds. Epic! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Do this as an async task, and figure out your approach, if you're doing 1000 queries, you already have a problem with design. Consider changing your approach.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a idea how I can approach my target on another way. 
I have a ListView, with around 180 entries (parsed from an XML, because everything is variable). Each entry come with 4 other data's, too (url's and names). 
Do you hav an idea how I can approch it on a better way?

Comment: Instead of throwing it ALLin one list, consider breaking it into pieces based on relations that way you dont have to query EVERYTHING.

Comment: Means I should only insert if I need it. Good idead, but how to get this working. 
I think this would make my listview laggy.

Comment: Timing is all you need to deal with, try experimenting. Since this post has sparked some interested in your change, if you feel it solved/inspired how to approach your problem, don't forget to mark it.

Comment: I think I have a little idea, how I can approach it. On appstart I insert about 15 rows. 
If I scroll in my ListView down, I insert 15 new. The only problem, is my search. I think I have to do the insert in a new thread an insert in background more and more.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree that the best approach would be to use threading, however from a UI viewpoint, as well as what is recommended by Android (long tasks can get killed to free space for more important tasks), I would recommend using a `Service`. If you can manage running your big process as a Service, but receive updates in you activity (through binding or broadcasts), you should be able to update the UI while doing all of your processing.

Additionally, there is some debate over whether JSON is faster than XML. With something this complex, it might be worth trying.

Lastly, consider cacheing your data using SharedPreferences (especially if the data doesn't change often between sessions).

Comment: The XML parsing is done in 1 second. The data insertion last about 20 seconds ... 
The data change is'nt in my hands, it can changed 5 times a day, or 1 time a week.

Comment: I dont think using the SharedPreferences for the data is a good idea.. theres way too much data to keep track of... not efficienct and requires way too much maintenance

Comment: That's a good point. A database structure would be more effective.